# How to pass an argument of parent method to it's inner calling methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to call a [file uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin. When a file is selected, the `add` method will be called from library. On calling `add`, I need to pass parent method argument `opts` with `add` method as argument.

Here is piece of code using with RequireJS library.

```
 return {            
        onFileChoose: function (e, data) {
            // I need 'opts' object here
        },
        start: function (opts) {
            $('fileupload').fileupload({
                url: '//testbucket.s3.amazonaws.com', // Grabs form's action src
                type: 'POST',
                autoUpload: true,
                dataType: 'xml', 
                add: this.onFileChoose
            });
        }
 }
```

I need the `opts` object in `onFileChoose`.

I tried with

```
add: function (e, data) {
    this.onFileChoose(e, data, opts);
}
```

Above code produces an error as  `this.onFileChoose is undefined`.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside the callback method, `this` is not referring the object having the methods

Use a closure variable

```
return {            
    onFileChoose: function (e, data) {
        // I need 'opts' object here
    },
    start: function (opts) {
        var self = this;
        $('fileupload').fileupload({
            url: '//testbucket.s3.amazonaws.com', // Grabs form's action src
            type: 'POST',
            autoUpload: true,
            dataType: 'xml', 
            add: function (e, data) {
                self.onFileChoose(e, data, opts);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

or use $.proxy()

```
return {
    onFileChoose: function (e, data) {
        // I need 'opts' object here
    },
    start: function (opts) {
        $('fileupload').fileupload({
            url: '//testbucket.s3.amazonaws.com', // Grabs form's action src
            type: 'POST',
            autoUpload: true,
            dataType: 'xml',
            add: $.proxy(function (e, data) {
                this.onFileChoose(e, data, opts);
            }, this)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It works great. If I declare `this.options = opts` inside start method. Can I add it  like `$.proxy(this.onFileChoose, this)`? So that `this.options` can be accessed inside `this.onFileChoose` method.

Comment: Can you please tell me why it is not best choice?

Comment: @JustinJohn I'll choose opt #2